# What's the logic behind the Ctrl-Tab order in Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tabs, internet-explorer-7, ordering

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Internet Explorer 7 (on Windows XP) seems to follow no sequence that I can work out.

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> even jumps around with no clear logic in what tab order is being followed.

It doesn't even work to the reverse as expected from using it in other programs, such as Firefox.

Please explain to me how this key combo works in IE7 because I can't figure it out.

Comment: Bonus question: Since I can't edit the "advanced properties", is there another way to specifically change this single thing? I'm not going to try hacking the corporate machinery, but this thing drives me nuts and slows me down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE 7's Ctrl+Tab switches to the tab that was last focused, not the tab to the right.

This is controlled by the `Use most recent order when switching tabs with Ctrl+Tab` checkbox in the Advanced tab in Internet Options.

Comment: Oh, and if someone happens to prefer the "most recently used" tab other - I do myself - here is a way to have it in Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122

Comment: Gah! The advanced settings are disabled, so I can't change this. Horrible..... but still, thanks for providing the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You might find this relevant, and also note that you can change the behavior in advanced settings: http://www.ie-vista.com/tabs.html